# Java Split into lists

Tags: java, replace

I have multiple lines like that, I'm trying to split them and add them to 3 different lists. "~" seperates them.

> Name ~ Age ~ Word
>
> Name ~ Age ~ Word

I'm using the following code to split it up.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path); 
String line;
while(line=br.readLine())!=null) { 
String [] splits =line.split("~"); 
names.add(splits[0]); 
ages.add(splits[1]); }
```

I have ArrayList ages, ArrayList names, ArrayList ....

when I'm doing splits[0] it does work, gives me the names.

but when I'm doing splits[1] for the ages, it gives me a breakpoint error. (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Any help? would you aswell recommend me for a better way to do it?

Comment: Use a debugger to look at `splits` contents, or print out `Arrays.toString(splits)`

Comment: you are missing a closing bracket at BufferedReader init

Comment: Please make sure to provide a full sample of your problem. This includes the input data you are parsing. This might help to solve your problem faster or easier. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to check the splits array for size before accessing it and if the size < 3, you clearly don't have 3 tokens on that line... In such a case you cannot add this token to the appropriate list.

Comment: Thanks. fixed with if(line.indexOf("~")!=-1)